# Installation error with RVM stable version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, rvm, runtime-error

I want to install RVM along with Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.9. I have tried to install rvm using the following command,

> \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
>   --autolibs=enabled # Or, --ruby=1.9.3

But, I am getting the following error.

```
Upgrade Notes:


  * WARNING: You're using ~/.profile, make sure you load it,
    add the following line to ~/.bash_profile if it exists
    otherwise add it to ~/.bash_login:

      source ~/.profile

  * No new notes to display.

# RVM:  Shell scripts enabling management of multiple ruby environments.
# RTFM: https://rvm.io/
# HELP: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm (#rvm on irc.freenode.net)
# Cheatsheet: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm
# Screencast: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm

# In case of any issues run 'rvm requirements' or read 'rvm notes'

Upgrade of RVM in /home/local/.rvm/ is complete.

ajesh.co,TION
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   I sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and
#   more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne


rvm 1.19.6 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Installing requirements for ubuntu, might require sudo password.
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Please help. Thanks. :)-

Answer (score 0):

The packages were not installed as apt-get was halted while executing, leaving apt in a locked state.

You can delete the lock file with

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

you may also need to delete the lock file in the cache directory

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

after that try the installation command again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I followed this tutorial, now I'm up and running:

http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Answer (score -1):

use following steps you will get solution:

```
1)sudo apt-get -y install curl

2)curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable 

3)source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm 

4)sudo apt-get -y install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion

5)rvm install 1.9.3-p374

6)gem install rails -v 3.2.9
```